# where is the extern file in C++

Tags: c++

In my c++ code I have an `extern` include like this :

```
extern "C"
{
    #include <gw_client/ose_gw.h>
}
```

I tried to find the ose_gw header file, but failed, where is this file? Or this file may doesn't exist in my file system?

Comment: lmgtfy: http://sourceforge.net/projects/linx/

Comment: @user3828398: Are there some `#ifdef` or `#ifnef` around?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's in one of your compiler's search paths, or perhaps it does not exist in which case your code probably will not compile.

On *nix systems, the search paths are usually `/usr/include`, perhaps some compiler-specific paths, and any number of paths you gave to your compiler via `-I` options or similar when you invoked it.

If you're on Linux, try `locate ose_gw.h` and see what comes up.

Answer (score 1):

This files seems to be part of [LINX](http://sourceforge.net/projects/linx/), whatever that may be. Ensure you have it correctly installed, and that `gw_client` ends up under your include path. Google would have told you that in no time ;)

Answer (score 0):

It is present in compiler's search paths,

the search path may be  `/usr/include`,

On Linux, find `ose_gw.h` and you get that.